# jwt validation azure api management

Tags: azure-api-management

I have implemented a jwt validation for api request through azure api management but it is failing.
The policy is something like this.

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Autherization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." require-scheme="Bearer ">
<openid-config url="https://myb2cdev.b2clogin.com/myb2cdev.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1ctest" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>169679ed8-61df-0695-4375-574c3287ee98</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://myb2cdev.b2clogin.com/97a8e403-f111-4454-8561-0c2881aae4a/v2.0/</issuer>
            </issuers>
  </validate-jwt>
```

Authorization token contains Bearer string appended.
ex token: "Bearer auserasereadnasewrewrwerwete...."
Note: there is a space betweeb Bearer and actual token.

Can any body helps me how to fix this.
The response is always :
{statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized.Access token is missing or invalid"}

THanks,

Comment: Did you get a workable solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the require-scheme="Bearer " from the  policy. It will still validate the Bearer token sent in the Authorization header as Authorization: Bearer xxxxx

Comment: It is still not working.When I remove Bearer from policy and from token it works fine.

Comment: How did you configure the policy to remove the string literal `Bearer ` from the token?